Not able to run the react native project using pnpm
Im using the pnpm script to run the project. Im able to build and run the project properly, after metero loaded the script im getting this following error message
Below I attached the error message which i received
 Cannot find native module 'ExpoApplication', js engine: hermes 
    at ContextNavigator (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:175304:24)
    at ExpoRoot (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:175276:28)
    at App
    at ErrorToastContainer (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:360077:24)
    at ErrorOverlay
    at withDevTools(ErrorOverlay) (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:359831:27)
    at RCTView
    at CssInterop.View (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:11004:45)
    at RCTView
    at CssInterop.View (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:11004:45)
    at AppContainer (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:87827:36)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://192.168.1.50:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=src%2Fapp:98144:28)

And also i have added My package.json for more understanding
    "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 expo start",
    "prebuild": "cross-env EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 pnpm expo prebuild",
    "android": "cross-env EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 expo run:android",
    "ios": "cross-env EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 expo run:ios",
    "doctor": "npx expo-doctor@latest",
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm",
    "start:staging": "cross-env APP_ENV=staging pnpm run start",
    "prebuild:staging": "cross-env APP_ENV=staging pnpm run prebuild",
    "android:staging": "cross-env APP_ENV=staging pnpm run android",
    "ios:staging": "cross-env APP_ENV=staging pnpm run ios",
    "start:production": "cross-env APP_ENV=production pnpm run start",
    "prebuild:production": "cross-env APP_ENV=production pnpm run prebuild",
    "android:production": "cross-env APP_ENV=production pnpm run android",
    "ios:production": "cross-env APP_ENV=production pnpm run ios",
    "build:development:ios": "cross-env APP_ENV=development EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 eas build --profile development --platform ios",
    "build:development:android": "cross-env APP_ENV=development EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 eas build --profile development --platform android ",
    "build:staging:ios": "cross-env APP_ENV=staging EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 eas build --profile staging --platform ios",
    "build:staging:android": "cross-env APP_ENV=staging EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 eas build --profile staging --platform android ",
    "build:production:ios": "cross-env APP_ENV=production EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 eas build --profile production --platform ios",
    "build:production:android": "cross-env APP_ENV=production EXPO_NO_DOTENV=1 eas build --profile production --platform android ",
    "postinstall": "cd ../.. && husky install apps/mobile/.husky",
    "app-release": "cross-env SKIP_BRANCH_PROTECTION=true np --no-publish --no-cleanup --no-release-draft",
    "version": "pnpm run prebuild && git add .",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "type-check": "tsc  --noemit",
    "lint:translations": "eslint ./src/translations/ --fix --ext .json  ",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:ci": "pnpm run test --coverage",
    "test:watch": "pnpm run test --watch",
    "install-maestro": "curl -Ls 'https://get.maestro.mobile.dev' | bash",
    "e2e-test": "maestro test .maestro/ -e APP_ID=com.obytes.development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/clerk-expo": "^1.0.2",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "^3.1.3",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@sectiontn/otp-input": "^0.3.7",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.6.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.36.1",
    "app-icon-badge": "^0.0.15",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "expo": "~50.0.17",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.11.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.11",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-image": "~1.10.6",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.7.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-localization": "~14.8.4",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-secure-store": "^12.8.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.4",
    "i18next": "^22.5.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moti": "^0.28.1",
    "nativewind": "^4.0.36",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.3",
    "react-i18next": "^12.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-avoid-softinput": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-basic-carousel": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.1",
    "react-native-international-phone-number": "^0.7.6",
    "react-native-mmkv": "2.6.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-query-kit": "^3.2.0",
    "tailwind-variants": "^0.1.20",
    "zod": "^3.22.4",
    "zustand": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.8.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.8.1",
    "@dev-plugins/react-navigation": "^0.0.5",
    "@dev-plugins/react-query": "^0.0.5",
    "@expo/config": "~8.5.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.3",
    "@types/i18n-js": "^3.8.9",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/lodash.memoize": "^4.1.9",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.48",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-i18n-json": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^46.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.4",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.3.0",
    "metro-babel-register": "^0.73.10",
    "np": "^7.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "packageManager": "pnpm@8.6.5",

Im facing the same issue in both android and ios
Node version : 18

i have the same issue, have you found a solution for that error ?

@SherifMoShalaby please check my comment

After installing the package expo application package
npx expo install expo-application

It started to working fine.
